# Update from ajax request in wrong order

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've 2 buttons that start an ajax request to retrieve some information from the server, in some situation like the subsequest described the displayed data are wrong:

```
-User click on the Button 1
-Request 1 start
-User click on the Button 2
-Request 2 start
-Request 2 end and print data in a div
-Request 1 end and print data in a div
```

The displayed data are now wrong because I see the data retrieved by the Button 1 but I expect to see data retrieved by Button 2

I've a lot of situation like this, how do you resolve these cases?

Comment: That is called a `race condition`. You want to be hard and control with a `variable` or such. %)P

Comment: You could just keep track of pending requests, and [`abort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort) them before making a new request.

Comment: Either you need to use ajax `async` call or you can call second ajax method on success of first ajax method.

Comment: Thanks to everyone I solved for now using a simple variable